# What is a good technique for evaluating this double integral?

Tags: calculus

The integral is: $ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x^2 - y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} dxdy $.

I'm having difficulty finding an appropriate technique for evaluating it. I initially thought that polar coordinates would be the best approach, but I am struggling to find the corresponding conversion of the limits of integration for this region in polar coordinates. I would appreciate any insight that can be shared, particularly that which gives an idea as to how the limits of integration should be changed.

Comment: The integrand switch sign if you exchange the role of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @achillehui I don't see that's relevant, though.

Comment: Aside from the issue the integral is ill-defined at the neighborhood of $(x,y) = (0,0)$, you have $$I = \int \frac{x^2 - y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} dxdy = \int \frac{y^2 - x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} dydx = -I\quad\implies\quad I = 0$$

Comment: @achillehui But Fubini's theorem is inapplicable, because the marginal functions are not integrable here

Comment: That's why I say "aside from the issue...". If you want to evaluate this as a straight double integral, you are not allowed to change variable to the polar coordinate at all.If you want to evaluate this integral using any form of regularization, any sensible regularization will preserve the feature of switching sign and you get the same zero for the integral.

Comment: @achillehui But that answer, I = 0, must be incorrect, since the question requires us to show that ∫∫f(x, y)dxdy != ∫∫f(x, y)dydx

Comment: If the question requires you to show $\iint f(x,y) dx dy \ne \iint f(x,y) dy dx$, then what you need is compute the double integral directly. You can't change variable to polar coordinates which mixes $x$ and $y$. However, let's say you want to fix $x$ and integrate $y$ first, you can substitute $y$ by anything you like. e.g. $y = x\tan t$. You will find

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} dy
= \frac{1}{x}\int_0^{t_0} \cos(2t) dt = \frac{1}{2x}\sin(2t_0) = \frac{1}{x}\frac{\tan t_0}{1 + (\tan t_0)^2} = \frac{1}{1+x^2}
$$
where $\;\tan t_0 = \frac{1}{x}\;$. The rest should be obvious.